# Listen to changes for a particular pixel on the screen in real time (in Linux)

Tags: c, linux, graphics, pixel, x11

I'm making a program in C, that needs to detect changes on a particular pixel on the screen, (on Linux using X11),check the color of the pixel and if it is a certain color, do something (ex, print something to console).
I need it to be superfast and preferably not hog the cpu too much.

Currently i have this code

```
// Get the pixel color
const char *getpixelcol() {
  XColor c;
  Display *d = XOpenDisplay((char *)NULL);
  if (d == NULL) {
    return "1";
  }

  int x = 959; // Pixel x
  int y = 554; // Pixel y

  XImage *image;
  image = XGetImage(d, XRootWindow(d, XDefaultScreen(d)), x, y, 1, 1, AllPlanes,
                    XYPixmap);
  if (image == NULL) {
    XCloseDisplay(d);
    return "2";
  }

  c.pixel = XGetPixel(image, 0, 0);
  XFree(image);
  XQueryColor(d, XDefaultColormap(d, XDefaultScreen(d)), &c);

  XCloseDisplay(d);

  // print colour of pixel in format #rrggbb

  // printf("#%06X\n", c.pixel);
  // fflush(stdout);
  char *hex;
  asprintf(&hex, "#%06X", c.pixel);
  fflush(stdout);
  return (hex);
```

^ this code gets the co-ords of a particular pixel (using it's x and y position on the screen). Im running this code in a simple while loop that runs forever with no delay. This "hack" works but is not ideal or efficient, and was wondering if there was a better way to "listen" for changes to a particular pixel, preferably in C but any programming language will do. I apologise if im being dumb as im not a developer and certainly not a C programmer.

*I am on Linux and need a linux solution, for X11

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a "hack", that's the only way. You first have to transfer the data from the server to the client and then retrieve the relevant pixel. That is done via `XGetImage` and `XGetPixel`. See: https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Transferring_Images_between_Client_and_Server and https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Manipulating_Images. I bet that under the hood there are optimized routines, which only transfers the data that is actually needed (instead of transferring the whole image - have a closer look at the member `struct funcs`).